# How to read form post data in angular4?As we can read posted params in .net using Request.Form["key"] ,how to do it in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular

How to read post parameters posted from .aspx page in angular 4? Like we can read post params in .net using Request.Form["key"] ,is there any way we can do it in Angular 4?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some misunderstanding.

You can send post, get, put, delete, patch request to .net, php, Java (server)

You can not handle post request.

You can submit the form.